# Correct Syntax for Comment-Based Help .EXAMPLE

Tags: powershell

Based on the information in the Powershell help files (Get-Help about_comment_based_help) the code below should be valid:

```
<#
    .EXAMPLE
        PS C:\> .\help_test.ps1
#>
```

The expected output when running **Get-Help .\help_test.ps1 -full** should be:

```
PS C:\Users\cbarton\Desktop\github\Powershell> Get-Help .\help_test.ps1 -full

NAME
    C:\Users\cbarton\Desktop\github\Powershell\help_test.ps1

SYNOPSIS


SYNTAX
    C:\Users\cbarton\Desktop\github\Powershell\help_test.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION


PARAMETERS
    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).

INPUTS

OUTPUTS

    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

    PS C:\> .\help_test.ps1







RELATED LINKS
```

However in my experience I am unable to have my examples show up in the same way. Instead the command portion of the example is concatenated with the path, with all whitespace removed.

```
OUTPUTS

    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

    PS C:\>.\help_test.ps1
```

Am I doing something wrong, or are all of the Microsoft examples wrong?

```
PS C:\Users\cbarton\Desktop\github\Powershell> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1012
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Very strange ... seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell *invariably reformats* the first (non-blank) line after `.EXAMPLE` inside a comment-based help block.

In fact, **you needn't even specify `PS C:\>` yourself** - it is added automatically, so that you get the same result with:

```
<#
    .EXAMPLE
    .\help_test.ps1
#>
```

However, an explicitly specified *custom* prompt string such as `C:\path\to>` *is* retained.

Invariably, however, **the implied or custom prompt string is joined with the rest of the line with *leading whitespace removed*, so that there's *never* a space after the `>`**.

**Given that PowerShell's real (default) prompt follows the `>` with a single space, the discrepancy should be fixed.**

Another problematic aspect is that PowerShell *Core* defaults to `PS C:\>` in examples even on *Unix*-like platforms (i.e., it uses a *Windows* filesystem path), which can be confusing.

[I've reported these issues on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6938).